# How to write to new file for each elements freq

Tags: r, file, csv, matrix

I am beginner in R
I have binary csv file, for example:

```
   a;b;c;d
 A;0;0;1;1
 B;1;1;1;0
 C;1;1;0;1
 D;0;0;0;1
```

I am read in R

```
data <- read.csv2("/home/beka/data.csv",sep = ";",header = TRUE)
```

How i can to write a new file like: For ex:

```
A;a;0
A;b;0
A;c;1
A;d;0
B;a;1
B;b;1
```

Thanks

Comment: `?write.csv2` : it has a `sep` parameter which can be used to tell it to use `;` instead of `,` and it also has a `col.names` parameter which can be set to `FALSE` to stop it from including the header.

Comment: Look into reshape2's "melt" function https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `melt` after converting to `matrix`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(as.matrix(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base R's `stack` to reshape your data.

```
df.out <- setNames(
    data.frame(rep(rownames(df), each = ncol(df)), stack(df)[c(2, 1)]),
    c("row", "col", "val"))
df.out;
#   row col val
#1    A   a   0
#2    A   a   1
#3    A   a   1
#4    A   a   0
#5    B   b   0
#6    B   b   1
#7    B   b   1
#8    B   b   0
#9    C   c   1
#10   C   c   1
#11   C   c   0
#12   C   c   0
#13   D   d   1
#14   D   d   0
#15   D   d   1
#16   D   d   1
```

Save as CSV file with `write.csv(df.out, row.names = FALSE)`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "   a;b;c;d
A;0;0;1;1
B;1;1;1;0
C;1;1;0;1
D;0;0;0;1", sep = ";", header = T)
```